# Why when i run linked program from cmd with java it doesnt work?

Tags: java, cmd

i tried to do this from cmd in window 8.1 the link is on c space folder

```
C:\> java -jar Minecraft-link.jar
```

> unable to access jarfile

But when I try:

```
C:\Documents\> java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

> Minecraft open and it work

why java cant use my Minecraft-link  and run it?

Comment: When you say "link" do you mean Windows 7+ symlinks? E.g., `mklink`?

Comment: How is this connected to programming?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Tenuously at best. :-)

Comment: for link i mean normal program link which we take for example in desktop and that was linked by the another program for example in documents that permit to execute it without open Documents folder

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the path when you call the jar file, if not, *file is not visible*.

```
C:\> java -jar C:\Documents\Minecraft.jar
```

If you want to include your jar to be executed aniwhere, you need to specify in your system variable `PATH` the `C:\Documents` folder so you can do:

```
C:\> Minecraft-link.jar
```

---

**Three ways to achieve this on windows**

a) Via `cmd` command line:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Documents
```

b) Steps for Windows 8 GUI:

- Drag the Mouse pointer to the Right bottom corner of the screen
- Click on the Search icon and type: Control Panel
- Click on -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced
- Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
- In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
- Close the window.
- Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

c) [Check this tutorial](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/set-path-to-jdk-on-windows-8-official.html).

Comment: Since when does Java honour the `PATH` environment variable when searching for JAR files?

Comment: @GyroGearless No.  CLASSPATH environment variable is also not used.  But if the command line is `Minecraft-link.jar` instead of `jar -jar Minecraft-link.jar`, PATH is used.

Comment: If java was not in the path there would be a different error. It looks like the jar file is located in `C:\Documents` so `CLASSPATH` is required when running `java` in some other directory.

Comment: java PATH are enabled and i told for only example that my link was in C folder but why i can run path of minecraft file but his link if i want to run it with java with his path doesnt work?